# Como funciona o processo de acesso a um banco de dados?

Tags: java, sql, banco-de-dados, jdbc

Eu comecei a estudar banco de dados e pra acessar determinado banco de dados com o JDBC é necessário um driver para cada SGBD(MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle), sendo que o acesso é feito em disco, mas como esse processo é feito? 
O SGBD funciona constantemente ou só ativado quando é feito uma consulta?

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sua pergunta está um pouco confusa. Mas irei tentar responder.

- Quando você instala um banco de dados (mysql, postgres e etc) o serviço do mesmo **deve** estar ativo, caso contrário você não irá conseguir se conectar com ele. Ou seja, caso o serviço estiver ativado o SGBD irá funcionar constantemente!
- O computador irá usar processamento apenas com o serviço ativo.
- O processo de consulta de dados é feito em duas etapas: 1 - Você se conecta ao banco (informa o login e senha); 2 - Realiza a consulta necessária

Comment: Obrigado pela reposta, de fato ajudou bastante, mas ainda não consegui compreender as seguinte parte:

- Se o SGBD atua como middleware entre a aplicação e o banco de dados, porque os acessos ocorrem em baixo nível e não em um nível mais abstrato, se entendi corretamente?

Comment: @jaojpaulo não entendi a sua dúvida. Poderia esclarecer melhor?

Comment: desculpe se não fui mto claro mas gostaria de entender como ocorre o processo de acesso ao banco de dados de forma um pouca mais detalhada e se o driver que é utilizado realmente funciona como um **driver** de dispositivo ou é apenas nome.

Comment: Acho que entendi. Vamos citar o banco mysql como exemplo. Após instalação do mesmo e com o serviço ativo é possível acessa-lo pelo terminal ou por algum sistema de gerenciamento (mysq workbench por exemplo). Esse sistema de gerenciamento nos ajuda na manipulação dos dados e o que é feito por ele é possível pelo terminal. Por exemplo: Acesse o link desse post e vais aprender como realizar o acesso ao banco via terminal: http://www.devfuria.com.br/sql/mysql-pelo-terminal/

Comment: Obrigado @Karan